# What value will be inserted when the DataColumn is AllowDBNull and has Default value as "0"?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have faced a problem with the dataset when inserting record into DB.I have a table **address** in which ***phno (AllowNulls=False,Defaultvalue='0')*** and ***mbno(AllowNulls=True,Defaultvalue='0')*** .While inserting record into database through dataset when I didn't supply any input to the both columns phno is taking default value('0') and mbno is taking "Null".I suppose both has to take default value when there is no input.

I dont know why this is happening.I have written code like this

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataRow dr;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from address",con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
    da.FillSchema (ds,SchemaType.Source );
    da.Fill(ds, "address");

    dr = ds.Tables["address"].NewRow();
    dr["sname"] = "tomy";
    dr["fname"] = "peter";

    ds.Tables["address"].Rows.Add(dr);

    cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
    da.Update(ds, "address");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the remarks-section of this [msdn reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) it is explained, what value will be inserted in which cases.
Since `AllowNulls = true` on your DataSet it probably submits a `null` to the database, which will let the database insert a `null`.
If you want to have your default value inserted, remove `AllowNulls` or explicitly remove the parameter from the insert statement (you would have to write your own InsertCommand in this case).

Btw, what do you want archieve by the combination of AllowNull and Default?

Comment: Is there any way to send the default instead of making the column allow nulls to false?

Comment: The default value on a null-enabled column will only be inserted, if the column is explicitly NOT sumbitted to the server.
I'm not into DataSets but i could imagine that the Column object can be used to retrieve the default value.  
Alternatively you could just discard the AllowNull, there are little reasons to use null if you use default values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, If you allowed Null in the column, ofcourse it will be updated with Null not the default value. So, either alter the column to Allow nulls=false or pass default value from code.